# CREATE FUNCTION SQL Server 2000

Tags: function, sql-server-2000

I'm creating a SQL Server function in SQL Server 2000.
My syntax is about like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.test()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
  DECLARE @A VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @B VARCHAR(100)
  SELECT @A='abc', @B='bca'
  SELECT A=@A, B=@B  
)
```

I'm trying to declare a variable and select it as a return value, but I'm getting this error message:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test, Line 10
Line 10: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Seems it wont accept a variable declaration. What's the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is for an Inline Table Function. with multiple statements as you have you need a Multi-Statment Table Function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.test()
RETURNS @returntable TABLE 
(
    A VARCHAR(100),
    B VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @A VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @B VARCHAR(100)
    SELECT @A='abc', @B='bca'
    INSERT INTO @returntable 
    VALUES(@A, @B)
    RETURN 
END
```

[CREATE FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258261%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

**Update:**
If you want an Inline Table Function is has to be only one select statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.test2()
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    SELECT 'abc' AS A, 'bca' AS B
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mikael Eriksson. It's solved.
But, should I declare the returned table (@returntable) first to get the result as what I want?
Whereas I just want to select 2 variable (as 2 column) instead.
Is there another pattern? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have updated the answer with an Inline version. That is the only alternative. If you need multiple statements in your function you have to declare the return table.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike. I've just realized it :)